# javascript get all html element by css Properties

Tags: javascript, properties, attributes, background-image

Is it possible to get With javascript the list of all html elements in body with Background or Background-image css Properties?

I want to change the background of all elements to a different color.

```
function color() { 
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
    for (var i=0; i<allElements.length; i++) { 
        allElements[i].setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#333;'); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I can go through all the elements. But it seems unnecessary   function color() {
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i=0; i<allElements.length; i++) {
        allElements[i].setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#333;');
    }
}

Comment: If you have the option jquery would be really good for this.

Comment: I'd like to but I have to use pure javascript

Comment: Then I think you will have to loop through as you are, but you could narrow down the elements you apply the style to, to only relevant ones, by filtering for specific tag names etc.